# Unable to save locally in Flutter Personal Expenses App

Tags: flutter

I took Flutter & Dart course on Udemy. In Section4 after making the personal expenses app. Whenever I restart my app the transaction history is gone. I wanted to know how to save them locally. I am aware in section6 some way of saving is shown but it just is too cumbersome.
Could anyone help me with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask questions more specific. We don't know about the course you took obviously. Edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask directly in the Udemy course forum, they will know about the sections that you are talking about.

Also here you have a cookbook about reading and writing files: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Also, you can use packages like [Local Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage)